# Does the touch bar work on a macbook installed with ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, hardware, macbook-pro

Keen on trying out the M1 chip for coding. But I much rather use Ubuntu. I believe the new kernel version 5.13 provides support for Ubuntu on an M1 chip. But will the hardware work if I install Ubuntu? Like the touch bar or the magic keyboard

Comment: Probably not....

Comment: Kernel 5.13 provides *some* M1 compatibility. It's a start. It's not complete. Apple has the right to make changes to ruin that compatibilty without warning. Mac-specific features like Touch Bar or Magic Keyboard might work, or might not. M1 compatibility is not complete. You're volunteering to do initial testing.

Comment: It's too expensive an experiment. Sucks that Apple is so rigid. Their loss I guess.